# how to autoincrement the numeric fields in onchange and onclick event function while table cloning using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, clone, alphanumeric

Can someone help me with this: I have a Maintable with one row and multiple columns , inside each td/column  i have another innertable with ids. I basically wants to clone the innertable in last td.

```
    <table id="innertable_0"
    <tr>
    <td class="policy_new_data  ">
    <div onclick="GetContent('familygender','0')" id="familygenderfirst_0"> 
    </div>
    <div id="familygendersecond_0">
       <select name="familygenderselect_0" onchange="changedropdownvalue('familyrelationselectField_0',this);showSelectedValue('familygender','0')" id="familygenderselectField_0"> 
          <option value="Male">Male</option>
          <option value="Female">Female</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

This is how I am cloning and appening to Maintable:

```
var $lasttdclone = $("#Maintable > tbody > tr:first > td:last").clone();

$lasttdclone.find('table').find('div').find('select').attr("id", function()
      {
         var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
         return parts[1] + ++parts[2];
       }).attr("name", function()
               {
                  var parts = this.name.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
                  return parts[1] + ++parts[2];
                }).attr("onchange", function()
                       {
                            //what should be the logic to autoincremnt the numeric field by 1, in the onchange calling functions

                         });

    ($lasttdclone).appendTo("#Maintable > tbody > tr:first ") ;
```

My probelm is: I am able to clone the table and able to incrment the id and name by 1, but how should i increment the number in the onchange and onclick function. For example, I want cloned table to have
 GetContent('familygender','1') instead of GetContent('familygender','0')
changedropdownvalue('familyrelationselectField_1',this) instead of changedropdownvalue('familyrelationselectField_0',this)

How can I do that. I tried regrex expression but failed to achieve the desire result. Pleas help. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

```
num=++part[2];
var fn=this.getAttributeNode('onchange').value;
return fn.replace(/(\d+)/g, num);
```

Other suggestions are welcome.